# Excel function that will respond if one cell has any of the words in another cell

Tags: excel, text, conditional-statements

Cell A1 contains text
Cell A2 also contains text
I want cell A3 to populate "100" but only if A1 and A2 contain any of the same words. Otherwise, I want it to populate "0" So, if I put the words "the dog barks" in A1 and "a cat meows" in A2, I would get a "0". If I change the second cell to "the cat meows" the cells then would share a word in common, and the result would populate to "100".

I would expect it to look something like this, but I'm really stuck past here:

```
=IF(A1 ****contains any of the same values/text found in**** A2, 100, 0)
```

Comment: Should it have a partial match or only full match? have you tried something / or googled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeap, A3 should look like:
=IF(A1=A2,100,0)